# Is there a way to overwrite defaul font for a specific app Android 5.0?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

An app I ran on Android system before Lollipop (LG G2 phone) where the system font worked inside the app, no longer affects the application (LG G3) in Lollipop. As far as I know, all settings are the same but the font will not affect the app any longer. Is there a way to set default font for inside of the app? I just don't understand because it was working before I upgraded by default to Lollipop but now, the plain boring font is set by default inside apps and seemingly unchangeable. I have not been able to find any information regarding this issue anywhere. Is there a savant out there to help walk me through this process to change it?

Answer (score 0):

From what you're saying, I pressume you're on a 'Nightly' or unstable version of a ROM, or if its an OTA update that took you to Lollipop, there's a bug somewhere. Keep calm and wait for fixes, or if you're impatient, then behold below:

By the way With the right search keywords, I found this called [Fonter](http://repo.xposed.info/module/git.hub.font):

> Instead of only being able to change your entire system's font, Fonter allows you to choose separate fonts for individual apps. And with a huge library of free fonts to choose from, you're bound to find the right look for every app on your phone. - [Quote from here](http://nexus5.wonderhowto.com/how-to/change-fonts-per-app-basis-for-android-0157763/)

I have in no way tried the Fonter, but I am sure it might be the solution to your problem, for the time being, until the actual issue is fixed

However, since you say that issue of yours wasn't there initially, I will suggest you fix the underlying problem, rather than go around with a 'hack', kinda.

Comment: It wasn't there initially with a previous version of android but when I updated to Lollipop, that is when the default font was overwritten and it seems to be inside all apps as well. I thought it might just be that permissions changed or maybe I missed a setting somewhere but I have not been able to locate the problem. Anyway, I will try that suggestion for now. Thanks :)